# Bad blocks and Link2SD

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, link2sd

I have a rooted Android 2.3.6 phone (Samsung Galaxy Y Duos, S6102B) and use Link2SD to acquire more storage for apps on it using a 8GB micro SD card (partitioned in partition #1 for my files and partition #2 for linked app data from Link2SD).

Well, it is the 2nd micro SD card I bought to my phone and the same issue appears: bad blocks. I don't know if it is because of the charger I use on my car... But the real issue is that with bad blocks on partition used by Link2SD to store files from apps, the SO become slow, I cannot launch apps or it reboots a lot.

Did anyone here encounter that issue? How to solve it without the need to throw current micro SD away? Partitions with EXT2/3? NTFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to "repair" the bad blocks and see if that works. Below is the Windows and Linux methods for doing it. Repairing won't fix damaged parts of the card but flag them to ignore.

**Windows:**

1. Plug your device into a Windows PC.
2. `Start>Programs>Accessories->Command Prompt`
3. If on Vista or newer, right-click and choose to runs as Administrator. If on XP, just run it.
4. Find the drive letter for the device. Let's say it's "G:" drive.
5. Enter `chkdsk G: /r`

**Linux**

Open a terminal (Applications-Accessories-Terminal) and give the command

`sudo fsck -a /dev/sdd1`

(Replace /dev/sdd1 with the actual partition device for the micro sd card) (fsck = File Systen ChecKer.)

---

Failing that you will probably need a new SD card. If it's the 'usual' FAT32 corrupting (which it does a bit) then you may be ok, but if any of it is damaged then it will need to be replaced.

Comment: Correct me if I'm thinking in wrong way: OS does not "repair bad blocks", but "repair the storage media" marking blocks with write/read error as bad, so after the repair procedure the storage media can be used, where the new available space is nominal one minus the space of all bad blocks together.

Comment: I performed chdisk yesterday, on that but I did it so much with the same issues using micro SD card, so I'm thinking about FAT format, that is so susceptible to errors, if it is best to change to ext2/ext3 or ntfs, if possible...

Comment: I heard that bad blocks are like cancer or virus, that multiply itself with time, so after sometime I have to change the micro SD card...

Comment: @kikbira hmm yeah I think 'repair' was maybe a bad word. It doesn't really do that, but in some cases it is corrupt and not physically damaged and can be 'repaired'. Chances are that it's bad blocks that are damaged and will be skipped. FAT32 corrupting on SD cards is like rain falling from the sky, it will happen!

Comment: I used a hammer and all those issues disappeared magically XD. As this one is a valid answer, I'm assign it as "the answer".